# How would the regular expression to search for 'number' on the next line?

Tags: mysql, regex, linux, search, replace

i need to replace 23K of records in a table and came up with a regular expression, though I know nothing about any other solution is welcome. the question is: How would the regular expression to search for '1113' and '21' on the next line?

```
INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.LOCALIDAD VALUES ('1113', 'CAMPO SAN JOSE', '3060', '21');
```

I also thought a bash script.
 Greetings all

Comment: Check this out: https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

Comment: Thanks @Allendar for answer , but This solution does not apply to my case, since I have the text file, and do not want to solve the replacement engine

Comment: Oh it's a plain file and you just wanna replace the lines? :P

Comment: yes , but only  first   and the last colums value

Comment: Yet you didn't really explain that in your question. Try `sed`. Something like Try; `sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' {} \;` How you make your RegEx, I leave to you.

Comment: Yes, sorry @Allendar . I 'll try to sed ,Thanks